# How to remove elements of a list?

Tags: list, erlang

I have implemented a function which deleting elements of a list one by one:

```
remove(_,[])->
  [];
remove(Elem, L)->
  Rest = lists:delete(Elem,L),
  remove(Elem,Rest).
```

But it hangs when I tried with this example:

```
L = [1,2,3,4].
remove(hd(L), [L]).
```

What is wrong with it? Or is there a better way to delete elements in the list one by one starting from the first element of a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes an infinite loop. First, you call

```
remove(1, [1,2,3,4]) ->
    [2,3,4] = lists:delete(1, [1,2,3,4]),
    remove(1, [2,3,4]).
```

So you call

```
remove(1, [2,3,4]) ->
    [2,3,4] = lists:delete(1, [2,3,4]),
    remove(1, [2,3,4]).
```

And then you call it again with the same input and again and again.

One way to fix it is to check if `lists:delete/2` returns same result

```
remove(Elem, L)->
  case lists:delete(Elem,L) of
    L    -> L;
    Rest -> remove(Elem,Rest)
  end.
```

(Function clause `remove(_,[])` is not necessary even it doesn't do any harm.)

But there is a more strightforward approach:

```
remove(_, []) -> [];
remove(H, [H|T]) ->
    remove(H, T);
remove(X, [H|T]) ->
    [H | remove(X, T)].
```

Which could be written using list comprehensions:

```
remove(X, L) ->
    [Y || Y <- L, Y =/= X].
```

The resulting code will be basically the same.

Comment: thank you sir , but still remove(hd([]),[]) raise an exception

Comment: @erlang You didn't say what the exception is. That's rather important.

Comment: never mind I fixed it where I am calling my remove function using case of

Answer (score 3):

simple answer is
A = [1,2,3,3,4]
B = [3,4]

```
          A -- B  = C
  
         [1,2,3,3,4] -- [3,4] = [1,2,3].
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [lists](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html) module, it has a lot of useful functions defined.

Take this for example, for you case:

```
1> A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
2> B = [2,3,4].
[2,3,4]
3> lists:filter(fun (Elem) -> not lists:member(Elem, B) end, A ).
[1,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```